# Error in toggle password visibility eye,Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment in code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, passwords, toggle

i wrote this code for toggle password,but i have error:
**html:**

```
<!--Hide/Show password-->
<button class="form-password__visibility" type="button" 
                       onclick="$('#inputPassword').attr('type') = $('#inputPassword').attr('type') == 'password' ? 'text' : 'password'">
<i class="vi vi-eye-off"></i>
</button>
```

**sccript:**

```
 $(":input[type=password]").click, function (e) {
        const input = $(this).closest('input');
        input.attr('type') == 'password' ? 'text' : 'password';

        if (input.attr('type') == 'password') {
            $(this).children("i").removeClass("vi-eye-off").addClass("vi-eye");
        }
        else {
            $(this).children("i").removeClass("vi-eye").addClass("vi-eye-off");
        }`
`
    };
```

**Error:**
I hqve error in html for this line" onclick="$('#inputPassword').attr('type') = $('#inputPassword').attr('type') "--->"Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment"

Comment: **Welcome to Stackoverflow**, `to maximise your chance of getting an answer`, please **[Take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and read **[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. `Update your question` with just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read **[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of things need to consider here

- You can use inline `onclick` **OR** `click` handler
- `$(this).closest('input')` means you have an element inside input and its totally wrong
- `$(":input[type=password]").click,` should be `$(selector).on('click' , function` OR `$(selector).click(function...`
- By using `$(":input[type=password]")` you're using the `click` to the `input` and you should use it for the `button`
- Your html structure for this should be an element holds both of `input` and `button` then use `.closest().find()` to select the `input`
- To set the attribute you need to use   `$(selector).attr('attribute name' , 'value')` that means `input.attr('type') == 'password' ? 'text' : 'password';` won't work at all .. the right thing `input.attr('type' , input.attr('type') == 'password' ? 'text' : 'password')`

Finally, Your code should be something like this

```js
$(".form-password__visibility").on('click', function (e) {
    const input = $(this).closest('.form-password').find('input');
    input.attr('type' , input.attr('type') == 'password' ? 'text' : 'password');

    if (input.attr('type') == 'password') {
        $('i' , this).removeClass("vi-eye-off").addClass("vi-eye");
    }
    else {
        $('i' , this).removeClass("vi-eye").addClass("vi-eye-off");
    }`
`
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-password">
  <input type="password"/>
  <!--Hide/Show password-->
  <button class="form-password__visibility" type="button">
  <i class="vi vi-eye-off"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: You're totally welcome  @sara .. have a great day :-)